# Mysql LIKE wildcard for sometimes existent value

Tags: php, mysql

The title might have been a bit confusing but I can clarify here.

I'm trying to use mysql's LIKE to match a value that sometimes is surrounded by a : or sometimes it can be on one side, or sometimes neither. I know of the wildcard % but that will select everything, so I found the _ which would work but it ALWAYS select that single character, I want to only select that character if it is a : otherwise not.

**Still confused? Here's an example.**

Say I got a column called 'name' in the table 'que' and in the column 'name' I got a value of 'sdfgsdfgsdfg:jimmy:asfds' I want to select ':jimmy:' but if instead the value was 'sdfgsdfgsdfg:jimmy' I want to select ':jimmy' only.

**Another example.**

To acomplish this with regular expressions it would be like this (:?)jimmy(:?) if that helps.

**Whats the purpose?**

I want to remove jimmy from that value and replace it with a : 
I'm trying to store Multiple name into one column and need to remove that one person.

I got something like this so far:

```
 UPDATE `que` SET `name`= CASE WHEN `name` LIKE '%jimmy%' THEN replace(`name`, '%jimmy%', ':') ELSE `name` end WHERE 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To acomplish this with regular expressions it would be like this (:?)jimmy(:?) if that helps.

So use [`REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp)?

> I'm trying to store Multiple name into one column and need to remove that one person.

Don't do that.  Use your RDBMS's relational capabilities and [normalise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE que_names (
  que_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  name   VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (que_id) REFERENCES que (que_id)
);

INSERT INTO que_names
  (que_id, name)
VALUES
  (1, 'bob'),
  (1, 'fred'),
  (1, 'james'),
  (2, 'michael'),
  (2, 'jimmy'),
  (2, 'fred')
  -- etc.
;

ALTER TABLE que DROP COLUMN name;
```

You would then remove all `jimmy` with:

```sql
DELETE FROM que_names WHERE name = 'jimmy';
```

If so desired, you could then retrieve your existing table as follows:

```sql
SELECT   que.*, GROUP_CONCAT(que_names.name SEPARATOR ':') AS name
FROM     que LEFT JOIN que_names USING (que_id)
GROUP BY que_id
```

Comment: Alright, thank you. I'll just set each value as its own row instead.